# Can't Deploy, health check failed. Status "Suspended" for AWS Elastic Beanstalk app

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-iam

I have an Elastic Beanstalk application that worked when I first set it up and was accepting new deployments, but the moment I added a new listener to the load balancer to allow it to accept HTTPS it stopped accepting deployments and the Status turned to "suspended". When I deploy it says: "Failed to check health. Verify the permissions on the environment's service role and try again later. ", but when checking my permissions I don't necessarily see anything blatantly wrong.